# How can write a python function that takes two parameters one being a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in python that takes a list of functions as arguments and an integer value. So a resulting call to the function would look like this:

```
myFunc([f1,f2,f3], 10)
```

or

```
myFunc([f1,f2,f3,f4,f5], 8)
```

or

```
myFunc([f1], 3)
```

What will the syntax of the header look like?

```
def printGraph2(funcs, n): 
def printGraph2([funcs], n):
```

Neither of those seem to work for me.

Comment: The former is correct and should work.

Comment: The first is correct. **How** does it not work? Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and *details* on the error you're seeing. We don't have crystal balls (not working ones anyway), how are we supposed to help you if you give us hardly any information?

Comment: Hmmm I thought I was calling it correctly when I tried it before. It does work with the former when I have the function as follows:

def printGraph2(funcs, n):
    print(funcs[0](n))

And call it like this: printGraph2([f1], 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version should work.  You just pass the list as an argument and then index it to access the functions in the list.

```
def printGraph2(funcs, n):
    func0 = funcs[0]
    func1 = funcs[1]
```

Comment: Or, given that the number of funcs is variable, you should loop over it: `for func in funcs: print(func(n))` or something similar.